# PHP SQL - can't find if user exists

Tags: php, mysql, exists

I'm trying to find if a user exists using this code:

```
$usercheck = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = '$user'";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$usercheck);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);

echo "<script> console.log('data=' + " . $data[0] . " + ''); </script>";
```

Data always returns 0 despite $user being equal to a name which already exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your query is open to SQL injection.  What's the actual query being executed at runtime?  If you do a `var_dump()` on `$data`, what is being returned by that query?  What does `$data[0]` actually contain in the results?

Answer (score 1):

try iterate on your result and show more that the first column  (should be the first column of the firts row is 0

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   printf("col0: %s  col1: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

or try refer to column name istead of column position

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   printf("colUsername: %s  col1: %s", $row['userane']);  
}
```

Comment: The OP is using MySQLi not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$data[0]
```

database field name, like

```
$data['username']
echo "<script> console.log('data=' + " . $data['username'] . " + ''); </script>";
```

Hope it will works for you.